# Redirect to Link from Link saved in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, hyperlink

I am developing an Web Application in MVC.
I have added a link in Database **eg:"www.google.com"**, I want user to redirect to Google on click.

I tried in many ways but getting the controller in address bar **"eg:http://localhost:/Home/www.google.com"**

> View Code

```
<table class="table" style="margin-top:10px;">
<tr>
    <th>
        Sr. No.
    </th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Details
    </th>
    <th>
        Status
    </th>
    <th>
        Tracking No.
    </th>
    <th>
        Tack Order
    </th>
    <th>
        Ordered On
    </th>
</tr>

@{int row = 0;} @foreach (var item in Model) { if (item.PaymentSuccessfull == true) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @(row += 1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryDetail.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Home/OrderDetails?orderId=@item.Id" orderid="1">Order Details</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrackingId)
    </td>
    <td>
        //Here I want user to redirect to Google on click
        <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrackingURL)" target="_blank">Track</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime)
    </td>
</tr>
} }
```

Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the protocol with the rest of the URL.

so:

`www.google.com`

becomes:

`http://www.google.com`

Comment: @ scgough...  thank you so much for the help.. It worked amazingly.